# How to format date model field in angular 2 form

Tags: angular

my model has a field date in mysql format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss"

in my form id like to show this field in an input with a custom format : "dd/mm/yyyy"

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.date" name="date" view-format="DD/MM/YYYY" model-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss" type="text" class="form-control datePickerUi" >
```

thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package called moment that allows you to do all kinds of neat things with dates.  http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but it looks like theirs a directive on github to do this. Seen here: https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime

you would need this code:

```
<input type="text" datetime="yyyy/MM/dd" ng-model="myDate">
```

hope it helps!

Comment: This is for Angular 1.